# Rails ActiveRecord Model design

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 3 models. `Users`, `Groups`, `Employees` all of the three have many to many.

- user has many groups
- groups have many users
- groups have many employees
- employees have many groups

So I've created two new models:

- `Departments` (handles many to many between `Users` and `Groups`)
- `Employments` (handles many to many between `Groups` and
  `Employees`)

I believe I have this correct on paper but I can not get it down to code properly as I am new to rails.  Because of this the data fetch does not seem to be correct.

This is what I have:
Employment:

```
class Employment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :group
  belongs_to  :employee
end
```

Department:

```
class Department < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :group
  belongs_to  :user
end
```

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments
  has_many :groups, :through=>:departments

  has_many :employees, :through=>:departments, :source => :group
end
```

Group:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :departments #new
  has_many :users, :through => :departments #new

  has_many    :employments
  has_many    :employees, :through => :employments
end
```

Employee:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :employments
  has_many    :groups, :through => :employments
end
```

I think biggest problem I have is to figure out how to get `total employees` for a user. In sql it would work with this query:

```
select * from employees where id in (select employee_id from employments where group_id in (select group_id from departments where user_id = 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you defined your many-to-many ActiveRecord model correctly.

You can do this to find the employees that are associated with the user:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@employees = @user.employees
```

If you would like to tweak your queries, check out this doc - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

This will allow you to do everything from eager/lazy loading, joining, grouping, limiting, etc.

If you want to use your original SQL to figure things out before you write cleaner code, check out the "finding-by-sql" section on the same page.